# A generic sensor name

Tags: java, android, sensors, android-sensors

Is there a way to get a generic name of a sensor? At the moment my application lets the user select a sensor from a listview. Depending on the sensor the application should do various things.

I've tried to do this with a switch case statement and using the name of the sensor as a parameter. But since the sensor names are specific to my phone model the cases wouldn't work on other phones.

For example the "SAMSUNG Significant Motion Sensor" won't trigger a Motion sensor in a nexus phone.

I've tried to use getType(), to get the type of the sensor. But not all the sensors has a type.

My question is therefor: Is there a way to get a sensor's name that would work on all phones?

```
switch(sensorName){
        case "K330 3-axis Accelerometer":
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Case 1: "+ sensorName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        case "YAS532 Magnetic Sensor":
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Case 2: "+sensorName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        case "K330 Gyroscope sensor":
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Case 3: "+ sensorName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        case "Barometer Sensor":
            break;
        case "MAX88920 Proximity Sensor":
            break;
        case "CM3323 RGB Sensor":
            break;
        case "SAMSUNG Significant Motion Sensor":
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
```

Comment: just a simple idea without knowing how the sensor names are on different devices. why aren't you checking for sensorName.contains("Accelerometer") instead of the full name which is device specific most of the times?

Comment: `case sensorName.contains("Step Counter"):`
Is that what you are suggesting? Euhm it tells me Required: String Found: Boolean. Can you provide with code example, I might missunderstand what you mean

Comment: I would do it with if(sensorName.contains("Step Counter")){ //blabla }else if(sensorName.contains("Accelerometer")) { //blabla } you cant do .contains() in a switch

Comment: Yea I suppose this could work. But I've read that using this man if statements wouldn't be all that good of an idea? I would need about 20 if statements to fit all the sensors in my phone.

Comment: yea I agree it's not that cool, but I don't see a nicer way at the moment.

Comment: Ye, well it's excatly what I asked for. Thanks for the help man!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to just check if the `sensorName` contains buzzwords like "Accelerometer", "Motion Sensor" etc.

```
if(sensorName.contains("Accelerometer")) { 
    //do stuff
} else if(sensorName.contains("Motion Sensor")) { 
    //do stuff
}
```